# How to split this integer into its original values?

Tags: c++, arduino

The formula for creating an **RGB** number is this:

```
R (value between 0-100) + G (value between 0-100) * 1000 + B (value between 0-100) * 1000000
```

This results in something like: 8017035

How can I convert this value back to its original 3 variable values?

Using and `esp8266` to run this code

Comment: Now you understand why we usually use 8 bits for each color value, as in `#define COLOR(r, g, b) ( (((b) & 0xff) << 16) + (((g) & 0xff) << 8) + ((r) & 0xff) )`

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Why macro, though?

Comment: @LogicStuff It's because macros are somewhat easier to read in these small comment sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

To find R, you could modulo 1000. The remainder will be R.

To find G, you could modulo 1000000, subtract R, and divide by 1000. The modulo will remove the B values, and then by subtracting R (which you already have found) will leave you with just G * 1000.

To find B, you can subtract R and G, and then divide by 1000000.

This will give you correct results in the case R, G, or B are 100. The current top answer by CoryKramer will loop and tell you the number was 0, even if it was 100.

Comment: That is correct, the previous answer by CoryKramer does not take in account 100 values.

Answer (score 5):

The exact same way but modulus instead of multiplication.

```
int color = 8017035;
int r = color % 100;
int g = (color / 1000) % 100;
int b = (color / 1000000) % 100;
```

[For example](http://cpp.sh/8kqxk), here's how the values would round trip

Comment: Wow,

Thank you so much for your fast reply! Your code works perfect. I had no idea it was this simple.

Thanks!